# Azure Pipeline not using queue time parameters passed from MS Flow

Tags: azure-pipelines

​I have the following pipeline with some parameters:

```
trigger:
- none

parameters:
- name: location
  displayName: Location?
  type: string
  default: australiaeast
- name: instance_numbers
  displayName: How many VM Instances of the same trype?
  type: number
  default: 1
- name: additional_data_disk
  displayName: Additional data disk?
  type: string
  default: No
- name: data_disk_size
  displayName: Data disk size?
  type: number
  default: 1000
- name: os_disk_type
  displayName: OS disk type?
  type: string
  default: Standard_LRS
- name: data_disk_type
  displayName: Data disk type?
  type: string
  default: Standard_LRS
- name: shutdown_overnight
  displayName: Shutdown Overnight?
  type: string
  default: Yes
- name: shutdown_time
  displayName: Shutdown Time?
  type: number
  default: 1800
- name: os_type
  displayName: Operating System?
  type: string
  default: Linux
- name: storage_image_publisher
  displayName: Storage Image Publisher?
  type: string
  default: Canonical
- name: storage_image_offer
  displayName: Storage Image Offer?
  type: string
  default: UbuntuServer
- name: storage_image_sku
  displayName: Storage Image SKU?
  type: string
  default: 18.04-LTS
- name: vm_size
  displayName: VM Size? See https://azureprice.net
  type: string
  default: Standard_F2s_v2
- name: enable_windows_updates
  displayName: Enable windows update?
  type: string
  default: false
- name: boot_strap_url
  displayName: What bootstrap to use?
  type: string
  default: https://incorrect-link
- name: team_name
  displayName: Team name tag?
  type: string
  default: Incorrect-Team-Name
- name: environment_name
  displayName: Environment name tag?
  type: string
  default: Test
- name: useby
  displayName: Usebay date tag? (When will you be finished with these resources)
  type: string
  default: dd.mm.yyyy
- name: release
  displayName: Release tag?
  type: string
  default: Update
- name: devops_work_item_id
  displayName: DevOps work item ID tag?
  type: string
  default: 00000
- name: owner
  displayName: Owner tag?
  type: string
  default: firstname.lastname@domain.com
- name: intention
  displayName: Intention tag?
  type: string
  default: What is the intention of these resources?

variables:
  Location: ${{ parameters.location }}
  InstanceNumbers: ${{ parameters.instance_numbers }}
  AdditionalDataDisk: ${{ parameters.additional_data_disk }}
  DataDiskSize: ${{ parameters.data_disk_size }}
  OSDiskType: ${{ parameters.os_disk_type }}
  DataDiskType: ${{ parameters.data_disk_type }}
  ShutdownOvernight: ${{ parameters.shutdown_overnight }}
  ShutdownTime: ${{ parameters.shutdown_time }}
  OperatingSystem: ${{ parameters.os_type }}
  StorageImagePublisher: ${{ parameters.storage_image_publisher }}
  StorageImageOffer: ${{ parameters.storage_image_offer }}
  StorageImageSKU: ${{ parameters.storage_image_sku }}
  VMSize: ${{ parameters.vm_size }}
  EnableWindowsUpdate: ${{ parameters.enable_windows_updates }}
  BootStrapURI: ${{ parameters.boot_strap_url }}
  TeamName: ${{ parameters.team_name }}
  EnvironmentName: ${{ parameters.environment_name }}
  UseBy: ${{ parameters.useby }}
  Release: ${{ parameters.release }}
  DevOpsWorkItem: ${{ parameters.devops_work_item_id }}
  Intention: ${{ parameters.intention }}
  Owner: ${{ parameters.owner }}

stages:
- stage: echo_responses
  displayName: Echo responses
  jobs:
  - job:
    displayName: Echo responses
    steps:
    - checkout: none
      lfs: true
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo $(Location)
          echo $(InstanceNumbers)
          echo $(AdditionalDataDisk)
          echo $(DataDiskSize)
          echo $(OSDiskType)
          echo $(DataDiskType)
          echo $(DataDiskType)
          echo $(ShutdownOvernight)
          echo $(ShutdownTime)
          echo $(OperatingSystem)
          echo $(StorageImagePublisher)
          echo $(StorageImageOffer)
          echo $(StorageImageSKU)
          echo $(VMSize)
          echo $(EnableWindowsUpdate)
          echo $(BootStrapURI)
          echo $(TeamName)
          echo $(EnvironmentName)
          echo $(UseBy)
          echo $(Release)
          echo $(DevOpsWorkItem)
          echo $(Intention)
          echo $(Owner)
```

And an MS Flow to queue the build and pass in parameters from a form response:

[image]

The pipeline queue's fine, and I can see the queue parameters being passed through:

[image]

However at runtime, these queue time parameters are NOT being passed, it's only using the defaults:
​
[image]

Seems like a bug, the queue time parameters are picked up fine from the Flow. Anyone seen this before and know how to resole it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it does not support this feature, we recommend that you raise a new [Power Automate Ideas](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/idb-p/MPAIdeas) ticket, their engineers will check it.

As a workaround, we can add the variable via UI page, then we can get the parameters from MS Flow.
A skeleton version looks like this:

```
trigger:
- none

stages:
- stage: echo_responses
  displayName: Echo responses
  jobs:
  - job:
    displayName: Echo responses
    steps:
    - checkout: none
      lfs: true
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo Location = $(Location)
          echo data_disk_size = $(data_disk_size)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it seems queue time variables set in the UI does work

Comment: Sure no problem. Thanks